# How to check which package created a group in Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, group

I've recently noticed some changes to the `/etc/group` and `/etc/gshadow` files on my Arch Linux system, which were presumably caused by a system upgrade:

```
+kvm:x:992:   # group
+kvm:!!::     # gshadow
```

How can I determine which package created that group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to search the [`sysusers.d`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sysusers.d.html) directory, which contains configuration files for [`systemd-sysusers`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-sysusers.html). In particular, the `kvm` group is currently created by `systemd`. This is the commit that introduced that change: [5a664ca1](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/5a664ca10f38dbf66c07961707dafed66382caec).

Answer (score 2):

With that specific group, the package is `libvirt`. But as you can see from the [PKGBUILD](https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/community.git/tree/trunk/PKGBUILD?h=packages/libvirt#n85) it is not the package that creates the group, but the application. pacman would have [told you this](https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/community.git/tree/trunk/libvirt.install?h=packages/libvirt) when you installed it.

pacman has its own concept of groups, but they refer to groups of packages, not user groups. So there is no guaranteed or simple way to immediately determine which package altered `/etc/group` or `/etc/shadow`. Your best bet would be to query the database to determine which package owns the binary referred to in those files, and then investigate from there:

```
pacman -Ss kvm
  community/libvirt 3.5.0-1
  API for controlling virtualization engines (openvz,kvm,qemu,virtualbox,xen,etc)
```

Comment: Amusingly, I don't have `libvirt` installed: `pacman -Qs libvirt` shows nothing. And the only file owned by the `kvm` group is `/dev/kvm`.

Comment: @eugeney Odd. It doesn't appear to have been part of the filesystem package in the recent past. Let me dig a little deeper.

Comment: Apparently, it was `systemd` that created the group. Check my [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/401181/903) for the details :)